# Display markdown in markdown

Tags: escaping, markdown

What is the way to display a markdown section inside a markdown document?

Let's say you write a documentation about **markdown**.

I don't want to **escape** every character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render it as code.

For [inline code](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code) use backticks, e.g.

- Use single asterisks for *italic* text: `*italic*`
- Use double asterisks for **bold** text: `**bold**`

The Markdown snippets in the previous list are written as `` `*italic*` `` and `` `**bold**` `` respectively.

For a [code block](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code), indent the entire block by four spaces:

```
    # Title

    * One
    * Two
    * Three
```

Many implementations will also let you use three backticks for [fenced code blocks](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/#fenced-code-blocks) instead of indenting, but this isn't fully standardized.

Comment: Good answer, +1. FYI, the original [syntax rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) can be viewed in their original Markdown [source](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax.text) (by added `.text` to the URL). Of course, that document shows sample Markdown code throughout. Makes for a nice demonstration of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<pre></pre>` tags?

Looks more convenient, as it allow clear code by letting the user type naturally, rather than having to quote line by line as inline `preformatted`.